# NSTimer causes crash

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, crash, nstimer

The following method causes a crash. The UI is like a button, which handles the start / stop functionality of the NSTimer. If the timer runs,  a UILabel is updated. Using the viewDidLoad Method makes my timer work, stopping it works too, but starting it again crashes the app.

Removing the alloc in the viewDidLoad method and trying to use the start button causes a crash *instantly*. Even the `NSLog(@"Start now");`is not called.

Code:

```
- (void)tick {
NSLog(@"tick");
float value = [moneyLabel.text floatValue];
moneyLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", value + 1.0];

}

- (IBAction)startStopButtonClicked:(UIButton *)sender {
if ([sender.titleLabel.text isEqualToString:@"Start"]) {
    NSLog(@"Start now");
    if (timer) {
        NSLog(@"Timer valid");
        [timer fire];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Timer is nil");
        timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(tick) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
        [timer fire];
    }

    NSLog(@"bla");

    [sender setTitle:@"Stop" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
} else {
    [timer invalidate];
    timer = nil;
    NSLog(@"Stopped.");
    NSLog(@"Timer isValid: %@", timer);
    [sender setTitle:@"Start" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
}
```

Comment: yes plz post your crash log so that we can help you...

Comment: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFArray startStopButtonClicked:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x683d8e0'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you have posted works as desired - just tested it in a new project, so the problem could be somewhere else. I tested it only by declaring the ivar `NSTimer *timer;` without any initialization in `viewDidLoad:` or the designated initializers...

Comment: Problem was not adding a rootViewController in the AppDelegate. WTF.

Answer (score 3):

I don't see the need to call `[NSTimer fire]` at all; it should be enough to allow the timer to decide when to fire.

Firstly ensure that `timer` is `nil` (it should be if it's an instance variable of the object), although explicitly setting it to `nil` in `- (id)init` won't hurt.

Next I would use the state of the timer itself to determine whether start/stop has been pressed, not the text in the button:

```
- (IBAction)startStopButtonClicked:(UIButton *)sender
{
    if (timer != nil)
    {
        NSLog(@"Stopping timer");
        [timer invalidate];
        timer = nil;
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Starting timer");
        timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1
                                                 target:self
                                               selector:@selector(tick)
                                               userInfo:nil
                                                repeats:YES];
    }

    [sender setTitle:(timer != nil ? @"Stop" : @"Start")
            forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

Comment: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFArray startStopButtonClicked:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x683d8e0'

Comment: @Darwin  That looks like a crash outside the code you have posted.  Given another answer seems to indicate that this code works, it looks like you are looking in the wrong place.

Comment: There is no code except this in my project ... Everything else is just standard like viewDidLoad. What a mess ...